# access mutators from Field input

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I have custom mutators to handle Slider value changes in react-final-form, like this [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-final-form-simple-example-vh2h3).
However, I want to have a function that generates Field/FieldArray in a Wizard, like this [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wizard-example-hkkv5). In FieldArray render function I can access arrayMutators and another custom mutator from fields variable. I couldn't find these mutators in the input variable from Field.

Is there a way to access custom mutators from input or access form.mutator in Wizard from the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Slider example is a misuse of mutators. That `<SliderField/>` could be done with just a `<Field/>` component.

[image: Edit Wizard-Example]

Mutators live on the `form`. If you really need to get at them, you can use the [`useForm()`](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/api/useForm) hook.

Comment: thanks. it works.  my question is actually how to change value of elements that are not regular input, like button, slider.. since I can use input.onChange(newValue), this solved my problem.  And I've updated second example to include Button updates value.